Merge Animation layers in NLA
I wanted to add like a pose change on an animation then merge anmation layers and continue animating normally in timeline, is there a way to do this in Blender?
I'm talking about Merging and not baking.. but even if it will key every controller on every frame it's alright as long as I can continue animating the Ctrl Rig normally on base-layer without having to continue animating on another layer.
Thank you.
